# Is it possible to install RPM build on Debian?

Tags: debian, docker, rpmbuild

I have a Docker-based Debian Sid build environment for Go. The build script of an is configured to build both .deb and .rpm.

The rpm build process of a component I  wish to build requires though the tool `rpmbuild`.

Is it possible to install rpmbuild on Debian or should I better try another Linux distro?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can install the `rpm` package which provides `/usr/bin/rpmbuild`.

Personally I prefer building my packages on the exact same OS as where the package will be installed to avoid dependency problems.